# Unexpected value for steps_per_epoch ValueError when running model.fit() in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a unet model using keras.

Whenever I try training the model I get the following error:

> ValueError: Unexpected value for `steps_per_epoch`. Received value is 0. Please check the docstring for `model.fit()` for supported values.

My model is

```
def build_unet_model():
    # inputs
   inputs = layers.Input(shape=(128,128,3))
   # encoder: contracting path - downsample
   # 1 - downsample
   f1, p1 = downsample_block(inputs, 64)
   # 2 - downsample
   f2, p2 = downsample_block(p1, 128)
   # 3 - downsample
   f3, p3 = downsample_block(p2, 256)
   # 4 - downsample
   f4, p4 = downsample_block(p3, 512)
   # 5 - bottleneck
   bottleneck = double_conv_block(p4, 1024)
   # decoder: expanding path - upsample
   # 6 - upsample
   u6 = upsample_block(bottleneck, f4, 512)
   # 7 - upsample
   u7 = upsample_block(u6, f3, 256)
   # 8 - upsample
   u8 = upsample_block(u7, f2, 128)
   # 9 - upsample
   u9 = upsample_block(u8, f1, 64)
   # outputs
   outputs = layers.Conv2D(3, 1, padding="same", activation = "softmax")(u9)
   # unet model with Keras Functional API
   unet_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="U-Net")
   return unet_model
```

and then I retrieve and train the model like so:

```
unet_model = build_unet_model()

unet_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(),
                  loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                  metrics="accuracy")

NUM_EPOCHS = 20
TRAIN_LENGTH = 160
print("Batch size: ", BATCH_SIZE)
print("Train length: ", TRAIN_LENGTH)
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = TRAIN_LENGTH // BATCH_SIZE
print("Here is the steps per epoch: ", STEPS_PER_EPOCH)
VAL_SUBSPLITS = 5
TEST_LENTH = 50
VALIDATION_STEPS = TEST_LENTH // BATCH_SIZE // VAL_SUBSPLITS
model_history = unet_model.fit(train_batches,
                              epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                              steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                              validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
                              validation_data=test_batches)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error. My terminal output looks like this:

> Initial shape:  (None, None, 3)
> Final shape:  (1024, 1024, 3)
> Initial shape:  (None, None, 3)
> Final shape:  (1024, 1024, 3)
> Batch size:  64
> Train length:  160
> Here is the steps per epoch:  2
> Epoch 1/20
> 2/2 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 371479.4688 - accuracy: 0.4182Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/user_name/repos/kerascv/keras_unet.py", line 183, in 
> model_history = unet_model.fit(train_batches,

So I would think that since the value I am passing in for steps_per_epoch is not 0 that I shouldn't be getting an error about that value being 0.

Comment: This likely refers to the validation steps, as you have 0 validation steps.